# How to refer to the parent of the parent correctly?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

There's an element `FlowChart` with properties `p1`,`p2`,`p3` ... `pn`. 
`SensorValuesSetter` must be able to access these properties by using the element `Button` which is located deeply in it.

I imagine the solution like that:

```
// main.qml

// ...

FlowChart {  
        id: flowChart
        anchors.fill: parent


        SensorValuesSetter {
            id: valueSetterWindow
        }

        // ...

}

// SensorValuesSetter.qml
ApplicationWindow {
        id: valueSetterWindow

        // ...

        GridLayout {
            // ...

            Label { text: "Давление 1: "; Layout.fillWidth:true; }
            ValueInputField { id: p1_val_field; }   

            Label { text: "Давление 2: "; Layout.fillWidth:true; }
            ValueInputField { id: p2_val_field; }   

            // ....

            Button {
                id: button
                text: qsTr("Применить")
                onPressed: {
                    valueSetterWindow.parent.p1.value = Number.fromLocaleString(p1_val_field.text)
                    valueSetterWindow.parent.p2.value = Number.fromLocaleString(p2_val_field.text)
                    // ...
        }
}
```

But in this case errors `TypeError: Cannot read property 'p1' of undefined` or `TypeError: Cannot read property 'p1' of undefined` appear.

Could you please explain me what's the problem? I guess the clue is that I   tried to refer to the parent's parent with wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ApplicationWindow` is no `Item` and therefore has no property `parent`.

You can either rely on dynamic scoping [(see more on the scopes here)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-documents-scope.html)

Or you pass the *parent* explicitly in a new property:

```
// SensorValuesSetter.qml
ApplicationWindow {
    property Item parent // Add the missing property. Maybe some other name...
    [...]
}
```

And where you instantiate it:

```
SomeItem {
    id: myItem
    SensorValuesSetter {
        parent: myItem // Set it explicitly
    }
}
```